# What is the equivalent to Dart's ! operator in python (for typing)

Tags: python, dart, python-typing

I'm building a website with a Flutter/Dart front-end and a python backend. I absolutely love Dart's rigorous static checking (saves me ridiculous amounts of time debugging), so I've started using type checking in python as well.

In Dart / Flutter, I can specify a variable as having type int or null as follows:

```
final int? myInt = 1;
```

When working with `myInt` at future points in the code, I can then tell Dart's type checker that the variable is currently not null by appending an exclamation mark, e.g. as follows:

```
final int myIntNotNull = myInt!;
```

In python, I can similarly specify a variable as having type int or null as follows:

```
myInt:int|None = 1
```

My question is: **Is there a similarly concise way to tell python's type checker that I am sure that `myInt` is currently not null?**

Comment: `assert isinstance(myInt,int)`? there is no simple operator for this ...

Comment: In Python you can **annotate** variables with types. This is a kind of formal documentation and not part of Python's typing system.

Comment: I suppose [`myIntNotNull = cast(int, myInt)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast) is the equivalent you're looking for?

Comment: @deceze: `myIntNotNull = cast(int, myInt)` is what I'm currently using, but it feels so unwieldy :-(. But please submit as an answer. If I don't get a better answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @MartinReindl Are you sure that `cast` is what you looking for? Code like `from typing import Optional, cast; a: int = 1; b: Optional[int] = None; a = cast(int, b); print(a)` passes even `mypy` typing checks and `a` is `None`.

Comment: Probably `myIntNotNull = int(myInt)` will be simplest way if you want to ensure that `myInt` is not null in runtime. `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'NoneType'` exception will be raised in this case

Comment: Please be more precise. What do you mean by "tell python"? Do you mean you want a runtime error to be raised, if `myInt` is _not_ an integer (i.e. is `None`)? Or do you mean you want a static type checker to infer `myInt` as being `int` type as opposed to `None`? Also: If you provide a bit more context, I am guessing, we'll be able to provide a more useful answer "ouside the box" because `T | None` is a very common situation and depending on the use case, different approaches may be appropriate. (You can edit your original question and add a minimal use case example.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some discussion and further research, it seems that the best option for this is to use the typing cast functionality.

```
from typing import cast
myIntNotNull:str = cast(int,myInt)
```